# Since the active player controls planes in the Planechase variant, does protection from a player protect a creature from planes too?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Alice and Bob play a game of Planechase. Bob controls a [True-Name Nemesis](https://scryfall.com/card/bbd/136/true-name-nemesis) and has chosen Alice as it entered the battlefield; the current plane is [Mount Keralia](https://scryfall.com/card/opca/52/mount-keralia) with one pressure counter on it.

It is Alice's turn and she rolls the planer die, rolling the Planswalker symbol. When she planswalks [Mount Keralia's](https://scryfall.com/card/opca/52/mount-keralia) first triggered ability triggers.

If I understand [rule 901.6](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr901/#6) correctly Alice controls [Mount Keralia](https://scryfall.com/card/opca/52/mount-keralia) and [True-Name Nemesis'](https://scryfall.com/card/bbd/136/true-name-nemesis) protection ability will prevent the damage it would deal to it.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. Because it is Alice's turn, she controls Mount Keralia:

> 901.6 The owner of a plane or phenomenon card is the player who started the game with it in their planar deck. The controller of a face-up plane or phenomenon card is the player designated as the planar controller. Normally, **the planar controller is whoever the active player is**.

And protection from [player] will prevent damage from objects that the player controls:

> 702.16k “Protection from [a player]” is a variant of the protection ability. A permanent or player with protection from a specific player has protection from each object that player controls and protection from each object that player owns not controlled by another player, regardless of that object’s characteristic values. Such a permanent or player can’t be targeted by spells or abilities the specified player controls and can’t be enchanted by Auras that player controls. Such a permanent can’t be equipped by Equipment that player controls, fortified by Fortifications that player controls, or blocked by creatures that player controls. **All damage that would be dealt to such a permanent or player by sources controlled by the specified player or owned by that player but not controlled by another player is prevented**.

Finally, a Plane does count as an "object":

> 311. Planes
>
> > 311.1. **Plane is a card type** seen only on nontraditional Magic cards. Only the Planechase casual variant uses plane cards. See rule 901, “Planechase.”

> 109. Objects
>      109.1. An object is an ability on the stack, **a card**, a copy of a card, a token, a spell, a permanent, or an emblem.